# Testing to see if a string only contains alphabetic numbers

Tags: c, type-conversion, ascii

I am studying C but am stuck on a program I've been trying to create. Essentially I'm testing to see if a character string only contains alphabetic characters `a-z` or `A-Z`.

What I have done:

1. defined a function called `strisalpha` to do this
2. called the function in my "test bench", which asks the user to enter a string

What goes wrong in the gcc compiler:

```
testBench1.c:21:28: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atoi' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     integerCharValue = atoi( string[loopPointer1] );
```

This is my definition of strisalpha:

```
int strisalpha(char *string)
{
    int stringLength = 0;
    int loopPointer1 = 0;
    int integerCharValue = 0;
    int dummyArgument = 0;

    /* Get length of string */
    stringLength = strlen (string);
    printf("\nString length is: %d", stringLength);

    /* ASCII Codes In Decimal */
       A (65Decimal) to Z(90Decimal) and
       a (97Decimal) to z (122Decimal)

    Set up a loop and query if ASCII alphabetic character
    */
    for (loopPointer1 = 1; loopPointer1 > stringLength; loopPointer1++ )
    {

    /* Convert character to integer */
    integerCharValue = atoi( string[loopPointer1] );
    printf ("%d \n", integerCharValue);
    if (integerCharValue >= 65)
        if (integerCharValue <= 90)
        return 1;  /* Upper case alphabetic character, so OK */
        else if (integerCharValue >= 97)
            if (integerCharValue <= 122)
            return 1; /* Lower case alphabetic character, so OK */
            else
```

The result always says I entered an ASCII character, even if I didn't. Please could someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: 1) `loopPointer1 = 1; loopPointer1 > stringLength;` --> `loopPointer1 = 0; loopPointer1 < stringLength;` 2) `integerCharValue = atoi( string[loopPointer1] );` --> `integerCharValue = string[loopPointer1];`

Comment: What is an "alphabetic number"??

Comment: "What goes wrong in the gcc compiler" - it is not the compiler which writes strongly discouraged code.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is your for loop

```
for (loopPointer1 = 1; loopPointer1 > stringLength; loopPointer1++ )
```

Arrays in C start at 0 and the middle section defines if the loop should continue not finish. So what you want is:

```
for (loopPointer1 = 0; loopPointer1 < stringLength; loopPointer1++ )
```

And then for checking each character you don't need to do anything to them as you can compare characters like this for example

```
if (string[loopPointer] >= 'A')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Chris.

Comment: I noticed on the last line you used >= 'A'.
What is the significance of >= as opposed to == in this program? Would it not just be ==?

Comment: It's doing the exact same thing as your `if (integerCharValue >= 65)` - if I'd put `==` then it would only match on "A" when you want "A" or a character after it which is what you get with `>=`

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` isn't what you want to use here. `chars` are already stored as numeric ASCII values. You can just set `integerCharValue = string[loopPointer1]`.

Your `loopPointer1` is starting at 1, so you will skip the first character in the string. In C, the index starts at 0.

Also, you don't want to return immediately if you find a letter. Calling `return` will exit the function and stop your loop. What you probably want to do is look for characters that are **not** letters, and `return 0` if you find one. Then, if you make it to the end of the loop, you can `return 1` because you know you didn't find any characters that weren't letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner function that evaluates to `1` if the string only contains alphabetic characters, and `0` otherwise:

```
#include <string.h>

int strisalpha(const char *str) {
    return str[strspn(str, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                           "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")] == '\0';
}
```

And here is a more classic approach with `isalpha()`:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int strisalpha(const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        if (!isalpha((unsigned char)*str++)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```